# Error al iniciar emulador de Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone

Hola amigos saludos a toda la apreciable comunidad, tengo este problema a alguien le a pasado si si les agradecería si saben como solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola harriroot,  además de la imagen por favor deja el mensaje de error como texto,  tus compañeros invidentes que usen un lector de texto a voz te lo agradecerán.  =)

Answer (score 1):

La causa de tu problema es que tu equipo no permite la virtualización. Para poder activarla es necesario realizar lo siguiente:

1. Inicio --> Buscar: Activar o Desactivar características de Windows.

Te abrirá la siguiente ventana:

[image: Caraterísticas]

Buscas lo opción de Hyper-v y la activas. El proceso tardará algunos minutos y te pedirá reiniciar el equipo.
Una vez que se reinicie podrás ejecutar el emulador sin ningún problema :)

*Si tienes duda de qué es [Hyper-v](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V).

¡Mucha Suerte! :D